# 'OpenTok/OpenTok.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opentok

I'm trying to use OpenTok for the first time. And What I'm doing is simply trying to run the Sample Hello-World Project that is given by Open-Tok.

I'm using Xcode 5, I have set my project Target to 7. I have also checked the libraries in Build phase of the target.

I have also solved such issued in past that has similar error of Lexical or Processor  issue errors by setting either Header Search path or by setting the Library search path in build setting.

I have also read the read me file associated with sample project and implement accordingly. Still I am unable to resolve **'OpenTok/OpenTok.h' file not found** error.I'm also attaching two snaps of my project explorer.

[image: Error] [image: Project Explorer]

I know I'm doing something silly here but I need to resolve this ASAP.
Please provide your valuable views.
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You haven't integrated the OpenTok SDK properly. The possible solution you can do is:

1. Remove the OpenTok framework you already added (even from your workspace)
2. Download it from http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/
3. Import this downloaded SDK into your project.
4. Import OpenTok/OpenTok.h into controller where you want to use the OpenTok framework.
5. This SDK is valid for architecture armv7 so remove other architectures from the build settings.
6. Run it on a real device.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have downloaded from this link only and it has got 5 sample projects I'm trying to run one of them. And I have set the architecture to armv7 too.

Comment: you are running hello project into real device ??    
http://tokbox.com/downloads/opentok-ios-sdk-2.2 download sdk from this link import it again and then try it

Comment: dude that i know but i am talking about target device that is decided before run.

Comment: mate have you downloaded the link attached to your comment?? its just a README.ME file attached to it

Comment: :) its my pleasure to give solution to your problems

Comment: Thanks for helping out with opentok questions @PitambarIndoria, email song@tokbox.com so we can thank you!